# SNR estimation from a radar sensor signal

Tags: snr, radar, sensor, human-detection

I am using a radar sensor for human activity monitoring which works on 3.18GHz. The received signal by the receiver of the sensor depends on the movements in its area of observation. All the activity corresponds to a particular frequency range. For example, walking activity has a frequency range of A to B Hz. I find the power of the received signal in the A to B Hz range and also of the remaining range 0 to A Hz and B to C Hz (C is the last frequency in fft). Suppose the power of the required range(A to B) is U and the power of the remaining range(0 to A and B to C) is V. Now my query is, can U/V serve as an estimation of SNR if someone is walking in front of the sensor?

Comment: The only way to answer this question that I know of, is to collect data on a large enough number of representative use cases and test your algorithm against these use cases

Answer (score 1):

No I would not recommend using the other bands as an estimation of SNR unless it is well established that there are not other variations that would happen in those bands. I would recommend establishing the noise floor for the band of frequencies used when there is no activity, and then the range (minimum to maximum) of power levels for activity present and then from that use the typical balancing of probability of false alarm versus probability of detection in setting the threshold for radar detection applications. The statistics and specifically the histograms of the detector output in both conditions will be very helpful to them optimize the threshold for desired performance (trading those two metrics). The other parameters of variability, such as gain variation in the receiver, should be minimal compared to the distributions of signal and no-signal+interference.